# Why is a UITableViewCell 1px taller than the row height?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController.  In viewDidLoad I set the rowHeight:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 43;
```

But then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I check the height of the cell:

```
NSLog(@"bounds: w = %f, h = %f", cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height);
```

This prints a height of 44 and a width of 320.  Anyone know why it would print a height of 44 instead of 43?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, the two things are independent of each other.

When you set `rowHeight` in your `UITableView` object, you are telling it how to render the table. The default value for `rowHeight` is 44.

When you create a `UITableViewCell` object, as a subclass of `UIView`, it has its own default `frame` and `bounds`, which includes a `height` (and `width`). The default value for `height` also just happens to be equal 44.

Your confusion arises because you have created a `UITableViewCell` object and you expected it to have a `height` equal to the (not default) `rowHeight` property in your `UITableView` object. How can it? It just came into existence!

Like all `UIView`s, until something comes along and explicitly changes its `height`, its `height` won't change.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I explicitly set the rowHeight to 43. Therefore I would think the default height of a cell should be 43 so it fits into a row.  What if I wanted a really compact table and I set the rowHeight to 10?  The cells obviously should not be created at a height of 43.

Comment: There is no connection between your UITableView and the UITableViewCell you are creating.  Note how all the delegate methods take a UITableView parameter.  That is so *you* can customize how cells are created.

Answer (score 3):

1.
Do not forget about UITableView separator (separatorStyle property) ;)

it has 1 px height.

Set `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` for plain-styled  tableView and you will see expected value!

Grouped TableView will always have separator and will be adjusted by 1 px.

2.
(tip) Use cell.contentView.frame (or bounds) property instead of cell.frame (or bounds)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can implement this method to return 43 no matter what.  You can also customize to your heart's content.  That's why it takes a UITableView as its first argument.  You could have multiple UITableViews using the same delegate.